# Massive counts of 4771 errors and can't determine the source

Tags: active-directory, windows-7

We've been having this issue for a while, various users, various workstations, and near as I can tell from viewing Netwrix reports, the users aren't even getting locked out. Literally seeing thousands of the following error per minute

```
03/02/2017 02:34:19 PM
LogName=Security
SourceName=Microsoft Windows security auditing.
EventCode=4771
EventType=0
Type=Information
ComputerName=dc.domain.org
TaskCategory=Kerberos Authentication Service
OpCode=Info
RecordNumber=13185523462
Keywords=Audit Failure
Message=Kerberos pre-authentication failed.

Account Information:
    Security ID:        S-1-5-21-1926054757-256335463-398547282-36898
    Account Name:       redacted

Service Information:
    Service Name:       krbtgt/DOMAIN.ORG

Network Information:
    Client Address:     ::ffff:10.101.28.31
    Client Port:        50728

Additional Information:
    Ticket Options:     0x40810010
    Failure Code:       0x18
    Pre-Authentication Type:    2
```

I've looked through Carbon Black, I've done memory analysis, I've suspected it was passwords expiring while a user's computer was locked and then causing issues, but eliminated that after some testing. I cannot find any kind of commonality at all. Anyone have any idea what the issue could be or how to track it down?

Answer (score 1):

If the ticket request fails Windows will either log this event, failure 4771, or 4768 if the problem arose during "pre-authentication".
In Windows Kerberos, password verification takes place during pre-authentication. 
You can get the details from [4771 - Kerberos pre-authentication failed](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventID=4771)

If such error appears randomly and for different users, then we can theorise about wrong typing. 
In my experience, most such problems arise when an user has more than one e-mail client and an e-mail server using AD infrastructure for the user authentication. 
In such scenario we need to investigate a root of the problem. Get help from this article on [How to troubleshoot the Kerberos error 4771 and locked user accounts](https://mivilisnet.wordpress.com/2016/03/07/how-to-troubleshoot-the-kerberos-error-4771-and-locked-user-accounts/).

Here is another informative post on [how to identify the source of Account Lockouts in Active Directory](https://www.lepide.com/how-to/identify-the-source-of-account-lockouts-in-active-directory.html)